# Revert changes / diff in a project without using version control

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In my current project I'm unable to use version control in IntelliJ (always been using git but can't now) and been thinking if there is a way to see a differences in files between the moment I opened the file (eg. today morning) and now (after I made some changes) like I can using git commit?

Comment: Can't think of any alternatives - why can't you use git?

Comment: I have to use RTC with Eclipse plugin so Im using intelliJ to develop the app and then eclipse to just push changes so would love to have something to check out my changes in IntelliJ instead of using eclipse for that.

Comment: I don't understand how that would prevent you from using git.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-local-history.html

Comment: Read the help page provided by @CrazyCoder. All JetBrains IDEs provide local history of the files they edit. All you have to do is to right-click on the file (either in the Project View or in the editor) and select "Local History -> Show History...". If you are lucky, the past version of the file you need is there.

Comment: that's exactly what I've been looking for. Put it as an answer and I will gladly accept it